# Run a cron as root user through cpanel?

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to run a cron as the root user, it works fine as the following:

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q home/user/tasks.php type=cron action=doTask /dev/null 2>&1
```

but when I add root it seems to stop working?

```
5 * * * * root /usr/bin/php -q home/user/tasks.php type=cron action=doTask /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: better(safer) to change the file permissions\group than run the cronjob as root

Comment: Base on which privilages did you create this cron job? I mean did you create or edit the crontab by root or some other user?

Comment: My php runs in root and needs to write to the same directory? It's some other user, I don't think root has a cpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to do this was to edit: `/ect/crontab` and place the command in there instead.

```
5 * * * * root /usr/bin/php -q home/user/tasks.php type=cron action=doTask /dev/null 2>&1
```

Running the cron as `root` from other users accounts didn't work because they didn't have the permission to use `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format, assuming that this crontab has root permissions:

```
5 * * * * su root -c '/usr/bin/php -q home/user/tasks.php type=cron action=doTask /dev/null 2>&1'
```

Or try running `su root -c 'crontab -e'` in the shell to edit the root user's crontab.